# porque se usa .build no fim dos comandos

Tags: java

Sempre vejo o ".build ou .builder no final das linhas em java.
Por exemplo:

ProductDTO.builder(); ou .build();

Qual a explicação para isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esteja se referindo ao padrão `.builder()` ou `.build()` que é associado ao padrão de projeto chamado **Builder**. Este padrão é usado para construir objetos complexos com muitos parâmetros, onde a criação direta através de um construtor pode se tornar confusa ou ineficiente. Aqui vc pode ver mais sobre o padrão de projeto [Builder](https://refactoring.guru/pt-br/design-patterns/builder)

Em Java, o padrão Builder é frequentemente implementado usando uma classe interna estática (ou interface) chamada Builder dentro da própria classe que estamos tentando construir. O método builder() retorna uma instância dessa classe Builder, e em seguida, métodos chamados no objeto Builder são usados para configurar os valores desejados, e finalmente, o método build() é chamado para criar o objeto final.

A principal vantagem desse padrão é a clareza na leitura e na criação de objetos com muitos parâmetros opcionais. Em vez de ter vários construtores ou métodos setter, o padrão Builder permite um código mais legível e fácil de entender.

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, obrigado.